# When would the component type of an array type be an array type as well?

Tags: java, arrays

[The introduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-10.html) of section 10 of the JLS says:

> The component type of an array may itself be an array type. The components of such an array may contain references to subarrays. If, starting from any array type, one considers its component type, and then (if that is also an array type) the component type of that type, and so on, eventually one must reach a component type that is not an array type; this is called the element type of the original array, and the components at this level of the data structure are called the elements of the original array.

I can't in practice think of any way this is possible. I don't understand why the components of of an array that refer to a subarray are brought up as a hypothetical. Does anyone have an example of this phenomena?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in this way that Java knows about multi-dimensional arrays. Consider the type

```
int[][][]
```

Its component type is `int[][]`. And the component type of `int[][]` is `int[]`. The component type of `int[]` is `int`. Here we reached a non-array type, which means that `int` is the *element type* of `int[][][]`.

You might be wondering why the definition of "element type" is necessary. Well, one place where using "element type" is convenient in the spec is:

> #### 15.8.2 Class Literals
>
> A class literal is an expression consisting of the name of a class, interface, array, or primitive type, or the pseudo-type void, followed by a '.' and the token class.
>
> ...
>
> It is a compile-time error if the named type is a type variable (§4.4) or a parameterized type (§4.5) or an array whose **element type** is a type variable or parameterized type.

It doesn't make sense to say "array whose component type is a type variable or parameterized type" because that would only include `T[]` and `List<Integer>[]`, but not `T[][][][]` or `List<Integer>[][][][]`.

Comment: I considered multidimensional arrays being the possibility but wasn't sure what the component type of a multidimensional array would be because I can't find anywhere in the JLS that explains what the component type of a multidimensional array is. I'm sure you're right, thanks for clearing that up

Comment: Your edit kind of confuses me. I thought java distinguished between component type and element type to specify that one may be an array (component type) while the other is never an array (element type). In the excerpt you provided I'm not sure I see the same distinction. What would be wrong with saying "components are of the type"? I think it says elements to specify that it is referring to an index that is not an array, am I correct?

Comment: @MatthewS. Component type may be an array, and may be a non-array too. The expression `new int[2][3][4]` creates an array with element type `int`, and component type `int[][]`. Your confusion might come from the fact that I didn’t provide too much context for the quote. `PrimitiveType` refers to `int` in the expression. So if it said `component type, the expression would create an array of type `int[]`. Also note that the part that I quoted says nothing about the dimension of the array being created.

Comment: So are they phrasing it as "elements are of the type" to specifically refer to the indexes that are not arrays?

Comment: Meaning when they say "elements of the array" they are referring to indexes that are not arrays, but when they say "components of the array" they may be referring to indexes that are arrays?

Comment: @MatthewS. At the start of chapter 10, it defined the "components" of an array and the "elements" of an array, and I thought you read it already. Maybe this is a rather bad example, since it does not say "element type" explicitly. I just found another example, which I edited in.

Comment: I read it yesterday. But I only remember it saying the variables of an array are called components. Then it distinguished between "component type" and "element type". I don't remember it distinguishing it between "elements of an array" and "components of an array." I understand the difference between "component type" and "element type" I don't understand the difference between "elements of an array" and "components of an array" Thanks for sticking with me, and yes your new example makes sense to me, but wouldn't `T[][][][]` be a component type of the array `T[][][][][]`? Sorry

Comment: I found where it distinguished! Now I know

Comment: @MatthewS. Yes, `T[][][][]` is _the_ component type of `T[][][][][]`, but ``T[][][][]`` is not a "type variable or parameterized type", so saying "component type" changes the meaning of the original sentence.

Comment: I GET IT NOW! THANK YOU FOR STICKING WITH ME!!!!!!!!! Then only think I don't get is how `T[][][][]` is not a "type varibiable or parameterized type" but `T[]` is. I'm sorry, every explanation you give me keeps on raising more questions, you can leave it here if you like, you've already helped so much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224875/discussion-between-sweeper-and-matthew-s).